# Notation to describe the adding of a constant to all terms of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I've been struggling to get down the proper mathematical notation for sequences. Suppose I have the following sequence:

$$A = (4, 3, 7, 3, 1)$$

How do I describe the addition of a constant to *all* terms of sequence $A$? For example, if I were to add $7$ to all the terms of $A$ to form a new sequence $B$:

$$B = (11,10,14,10,8)$$

How do I describe $B$ in terms of $A$? Would this be the proper notation:

$$B = A + 7$$

By the way, is even my notation for $A$ correct?

Comment: $B=A+7(1,1,1,1,1)$

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Is there a more succinct way to write this in the case of very long sequences?

Comment: Heh. One could always write $B=A+7(1, 1, \dots , 1)$ but I rather expect you were looking for something different. On a more serious note, you could adopt a two-step approach, first defining $U=(1, \dots 1)$ and then writing $B=A+7U$, thinking in terms of basic linear algebra.

Comment: @RickDecker This [N-Tuples webpage](http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/vectorc/3d/nplets.html) on the MIT web server suggests that `one can also operate on a tuple by a single real number`. Is this a universal convention (just adding by the constant after enumerating the tuple), or just specific to the author of this page?

Comment: It's not an operator I've seen before, but it makes perfect sense as a shorthand for what I've described. You could always say something like "define $A + k$ to mean ..." and then continue, using that definition as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unusual to see finite sequences written out in that way or any other. Given that you had a sequence (or net) $(a_i)_{i\in I}$, you could write $(a_i+1)_{i\in I}$ for the sequence obtained from the first by adding $1$ to each value.

Comment: So in my particular case, would the correct expression be: $B_i = (A_i + 1)_{i\in I}$? Furthermore, since these are finite sequences, how do I properly define $I$?

Comment: No, you would definitely not write it like that. "For each $i\in I$, let $B_i=A_i+1$" would be nice and clear. Or "For $i=1,2,\ldots,6$ ...." Or "For $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,5\}$...." Or "For $i \in 6$ ..." (where $6=\{0,1,\ldots,5\}$). Or "For $i\in \omega_6$ ..." (where $\omega$ is the set of all finite ordinals). There are lots of options, depending on context. Worry less about notation and more about saying what you mean.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: I should also note that if it's clear that the indices are positive integers, then casual notation like $(a_i)_{i\le 6}$ can work well. Or for general integers, $(a_i)_{-4\le i\le 7}$. Or if the set of indices is clear from context, it can even be dropped altogether, leaving just $(a_i)$.